# Using react native to Share a link and String not working

Tags: react-native, share

In using [react native share](https://github.com/EstebanFuentealba/react-native-share), I come across this error. My code can be seen below, I am not entirely certain what it means.

Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of `Tabs`. [image]

## Share.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  Clipboard,
  ToastAndroid,
  AlertIOS,
  Platform
} from 'react-native';
import Share, {ShareSheet, Button} from 'react-native-share';

class TestShare extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      visible: false
    }
  }
  onCancel() {
    console.log("CANCEL")
    this.setState({visible:false});
  }
  onOpen() {
    console.log("OPEN")
    this.setState({visible:true});
  }
  render() {

    let shareOptions = {
      title: "React Native",
      message: "Hola mundo",
      url: "http://facebook.github.io/react-native/",
      subject: "Share Link" //  for email
    };

    let shareImageBase64 = {
      title: "React Native",
      message: "Hola mundo",
      url: REACT_ICON,
      subject: "Share Link" //  for email
    };

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>


        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{
          Share.open(shareImageBase64);
        }}>
          <View style={styles.instructions}>
            <Text>Simple Share Image Base 64</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{
          Share.open(shareOptions);
        }}>
          <View style={styles.instructions}>
            <Text>Simple Share</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onOpen.bind(this)}>
          <View style={styles.instructions}>
            <Text>Share UI Component</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <ShareSheet visible={this.state.visible} onCancel={this.onCancel.bind(this)}>
          <Button iconSrc={{ uri: TWITTER_ICON }}
                  onPress={()=>{
              this.onCancel();
              setTimeout(() => {
                Share.shareSingle(Object.assign(shareOptions, {
                  "social": "twitter"
                }));
              },300);
            }}>Twitter</Button>
          <Button iconSrc={{ uri: FACEBOOK_ICON }}
                  onPress={()=>{
              this.onCancel();
              setTimeout(() => {
                Share.shareSingle(Object.assign(shareOptions, {
                  "social": "facebook"
                }));
              },300);
            }}>Facebook</Button>
          <Button iconSrc={{ uri: WHATSAPP_ICON }}
                  onPress={()=>{
              this.onCancel();
              setTimeout(() => {
                Share.shareSingle(Object.assign(shareOptions, {
                  "social": "whatsapp"
                }));
              },300);
            }}>Whatsapp</Button>
          <Button iconSrc={{ uri: GOOGLE_PLUS_ICON }}
                  onPress={()=>{
              this.onCancel();
              setTimeout(() => {
                Share.shareSingle(Object.assign(shareOptions, {
                  "social": "googleplus"
                }));
              },300);
            }}>Google +</Button>
          <Button iconSrc={{ uri: EMAIL_ICON }}
                  onPress={()=>{
              this.onCancel();
              setTimeout(() => {
                Share.shareSingle(Object.assign(shareOptions, {
                  "social": "email"
                }));
              },300);
            }}>Email</Button>
          <Button
            iconSrc={{ uri: CLIPBOARD_ICON }}
            onPress={()=>{
              this.onCancel();
              setTimeout(() => {
                if(typeof shareOptions["url"] !== undefined) {
                  Clipboard.setString(shareOptions["url"]);
                  if (Platform.OS === "android") {
                    ToastAndroid.show('Link copiado al portapapeles', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
                  } else if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
                    AlertIOS.alert('Link copiado al portapapeles');
                  }
                }
              },300);
            }}>Copy Link</Button>
          <Button iconSrc={{ uri: MORE_ICON }}
            onPress={()=>{
              this.onCancel();
              setTimeout(() => {
                Share.open(shareOptions)
              },300);
            }}>More</Button>
        </ShareSheet>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  instructions: {
    marginTop: 20,
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
});

//  twitter icon
const TWITTER_ICON = "data:image/png;base64,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";

//  facebook icon
const FACEBOOK_ICON = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADwAAAA8CAMAAAANIilAAAAAYFBMVEUAAAAAQIAAWpwAX5kAX5gAX5gAX5gAXJwAXpgAWZ8AX5gAXaIAX5gAXpkAVaoAX5gAXJsAX5gAX5gAYJkAYJkAXpoAX5gAX5gAX5kAXpcAX5kAX5gAX5gAX5YAXpoAYJijtTrqAAAAIHRSTlMABFis4vv/JL0o4QvSegbnQPx8UHWwj4OUgo7Px061qCrcMv8AAAB0SURBVEjH7dK3DoAwDEVRqum9BwL//5dIscQEEjFiCPhubziTbVkc98dsx/V8UGnbIIQjXRvFQMZJCnScAR3nxQNcIqrqRqWHW8Qd6cY94oGER8STMVioZsQLLnEXw1mMr5OqFdGGS378wxgzZvwO5jiz2wFnjxABOufdfQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";

//  whatsapp icon
const WHATSAPP_ICON = "data:image/png;base64,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";

//  gplus icon
const GOOGLE_PLUS_ICON = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADwAAAA8CAMAAAANIilAAAACQ1BMVEUAAAD/RDP/STX9Sjb+STT+SjX+SjX+SjX+STT/SzP/Sjb/SzX/VVX/SDb+SDP+SjX9RzT9STT9SjT+STX+SjT9SjT/SST/TTP+SjX+SjX/RDP/RzP+SjX+SjX/STf9SDX/SjX/TU3+Sjb+SjX/Qyz/Szb+SjX/TTP+SjX9STX+SjP/TTX9Szb+Szb/YCD/SzX/SzX+Sjb+STX/TTX/SzX/Szb/TDT+SjX9SzX/STf+TDX/SjT9SzX9Szb+SjX/SjX/SzX/STT9SjT9TDT+SDT/VQD9STX/STX9SjX+SjX9STX+SzT/UDD9Sjb+SjX9RzT/QED+SjT+SjX/XS7+SjX/Ui7/RC3+SjX/TTz/RzP+SjX/TTP/STf+SjX/STT/RjP+Sjb/SzX/Szz/Rjr/RzL+RzP+SjX/Szf/SjX9Sjb+SjX+Sjb+SjX+SjX+SjX/STf/SjT/SjT9SjX9SzT+RzT+STT/STT+SjX/STP/Tjf+SjX/Szb/SjX/STX9SjX/SjT/AAD/SjH/STb+SzX+Sjb+SjT9SDT+Sjb+SjX9STf9STT/SDX/TDf+STb/TjT/TjH+SjX+SDT/Sjb9SzX9RzX+TDT/TUD/STX+SjX+STX/VTn/QjH/SjX+SjX/Ri7+Szb/TTP+SjX/SDX/STT9SjX+SjX/SDL/TjT9Sjb/RjL+SjX9SzX/QED/TDT+SjX+SjX9STX/RjX/VSv/Rzb/STX/ORz/UDD9SzX+Sjb/STT9SzP+SzX+SjX+SjX9Szb/Ti//ZjPPn7DtAAAAwXRSTlMAD1uiy+j5/8FBZHQDY9zvnYSc5dGhBwr+1S0Zqu44mz4KtNkXY7Yo8YLcfp3bCGZ+sLhWaks2z4wO6VOklrtWRFSXos4DoD+D/ZnoEKasjwS7+gvfHC3kHmjtMlTXYjfZXBEWa+/nQRiK5u7c8vVGRWepp6+5eulQF/dfSHSQdQEfdrzguZzm+4KSQyW1JxrAvCaCiLYUc8nGCR9h6gvzFM41MZHhYDGYTMejCEDi3osdBj1+CSCWyGyp1PC3hUEF/yhErwAAAjFJREFUSMft1tdfE0EQB/ADJD+JKAomHoqKxhJLFCnSpdgIxobYgqhYaJKIHVQUsSFiBSuCvWPv3T/N2ZPD3EucvVcyL3sz2W8+l73ZvShKKEIxcCIsPGJQpAV9MThK1KzAEAaNHjosZviI2DgBR9psVrvCx6Ni1fjRNI5JIDx2nF5m4ejxsCRqVxMmknZMksGTVUzpu5zqJD1NAodNB2boyUzCrlnK7CSKOUCyGJOC4BSan6onaWLN5irpCIwgOAMBt5eZRVk2H+fQx7n92TzK8pT8AopCwCbGgiB4Pk1fsFDPFlG2mL9gRTTdnahnxcASDx/nq6SX6tkyYLnEo1qxknBJ2t9kVSlcq2WaZM1a0qXrtOv18Jbp9Q3l5Rv/39ubHKQ3V2xRtm7bXlkluyGra2qJ76jzwb/TxH721O9K3U1fsMfsgbCXcLFZvI+wL8ok3i/6+ECDOdxYJ/TBQ9Kw+nDTkRyHtodKjjbLyGMtx304cTKi8NRpoVutfJp5xgtv21ntxGw/J7T3PNdeuAhcuqxn9o5W0p1Ma78CpF/9lzdfI3ydiStobrjhIL4BRN7k4WRa3i5D5RbQ3cPDMcDtO4ZKGXCXedtuQL1nqNwHHjDxQ/rNGYbKI/gfM/ETwv6ngafSM3RwH3O7eK86Wzz9L582PO9lN9iLl6KpXr2uf9P7tvHde4e75oNEZ3/85NQ2hKUyzg/1c57klur68vXbd9XtdP34+et36C9WKAZo/AEHHmXeIIIUCQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";

//  email icon
const EMAIL_ICON = "data:image/png;base64,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";

//  clipboard icon
const CLIPBOARD_ICON = "data:image/png;base64,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";

//  more icon
const MORE_ICON = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADwAAAA8CAMAAAANIilAAAAAQlBMVEUAAABEREQ9PT0/Pz8/Pz9AQEA7OzszMzM/Pz8/Pz9FRUU/Pz8/Pz9VVVUAAAA/Pz8+Pj4/Pz8/Pz9BQUFAQEA/Pz+e9yGtAAAAFnRSTlMAD5bv9KgaFJ/yGv+zAwGltPH9LyD5QNQoVwAAAF5JREFUSMft0EkKwCAQRFHHqEnUON3/qkmDuHMlZlVv95GCRsYAAAD+xYVU+hhprHPWjDy1koJPx+L63L5XiJQx9PQPpZiOEz3n0qs2ylZ7lkyZ9oyXzl76MAAAgD1eJM8FMZg0rF4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=";


const REACT_ICON = 'data:image/png;base64,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';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('TestShare', () => TestShare);
```

## Tabs File

```
[![import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { TabBarIOS } from 'react-native'

import Share from '../components/Share'
import SaveQuote from '../components/SaveQuote'
import Home from '../containers/navRootContainer'
import MoreMenu from '../components/MoreMenu'

class Tabs extends Component {
  _changeTab (i) {
    const { changeTab } = this.props
    changeTab(i)
  }
  _renderTabContent (key) {
    switch (key) {
      case 'home':
        return <Home />
      case 'share':
        return <Share />
      case 'savequote':
        return <SaveQuote />
      case 'moremenu':
        return <MoreMenu />
    }
  }
  render () {
    const tabs = this.props.tabs.tabs.map((tab, i) => {
      return (
        <TabBarIOS.Item 
          key={tab.key}
          icon={tab.icon}
          selectedIcon={tab.selectedIcon}
          title={tab.title}
          onPress={() => this._changeTab(i)}
          selected={this.props.tabs.index === i}>
          {this._renderTabContent(tab.key)}
        </TabBarIOS.Item>
      )
    })
    return (
      <TabBarIOS tintColor='white' barTintColor="black">
        {tabs}
      </TabBarIOS>
    )
  }
}

export default Tabs][2]][2]
```